# Vagrant up error: I can ssh but nginx is giving me errors

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am using Vagrant/Homestead combo with Laravel 5.2 and I tried to make HTTP calls to the server and something broke but I don't know why, I kept getting a 405 bad gateway error and someone recommended I just create a new vagrant box.

So I went to my VirtualBox Manager and deleted my homestead box/deleted all files as well, then ran vagrant up to create a new one and I was able to ssh just fine but now when I try to make a HTTP call, namely in Postman, I get:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>

    <body bgcolor="white">

        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>

        <hr>
        <center>nginx/1.9.7</center>

    </body>

</html>

<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->

<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

When running vagrant up, I get this error (look at the very last line):

```
Lansana@DESKTOP-UV14VGF MINGW64 ~/Homestead (master) $ vagrant up Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: homestead
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 80 => 8000 (adapter 1)
    default: 443 => 44300 (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 => 33060 (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 => 54320 (adapter 1)
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/Lansana/Homestead
    default: /home/vagrant/Sites => C:/Users/Lansana/Homestead/Projects
==> default: Running provisioner: file...
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC4q2BHIAHJ/yUc9zwJVCUbtbPe5xPJmbsbUJmtjldEnaIZ00tG/memsDHbOlGsbTxRU2QgKmrKSu7Iz8r+FglDbXLzbrg0O9rrQWi9FCpl8J630o1/fz3vejVIslcnuRBtiW/UUjYTZ5vsU2E/aMmxJFA31IzWslmQKHzOW+2XHyQ3e8QQBI7owA4QpVHtki0g0xlISA+H7kgG90NY0uEF+t4GK0KY/CN2GzxMFCAxtXLa2M8uGimySImsPBZByMNuLsdiok8W8vLWtDr9qvXhQkXOpxSTUflfCiJQmOke3hJpjWGPCcaVg9gPmr3wH9GUKnGQJ6SPQlslMI+Mekr/ lansana@homestead
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/Lansana/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20160109-5024-pucyip.sh
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: C:/Users/Lansana/AppData/Local/Temp/vagrant-shell20160109-5024-1dw603v.sh
==> default: nginx stop/waiting
==> default: nginx start/running, process 1943
==> default: php5-fpm: unrecognized service The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what went wrong.
```

Anyone know what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following:

```
$ composer remove laravel/homestead
$ composer clear-cache
$ composer require laravel/homestead
$ vagrant destroy && vagrant up
```

For some reason, doing a `composer update laravel/homestead` didn't grab the latest version of the homestead files (I think it has something to do with the `composer.json` using `"^3.0"`, and didn't think `3.0.1` required an update or something), I noticed `homestead.rb` was not the current version.